# Why is my code not generating any figures, without it giving errors?

Tags: matlab, text-files, matlab-figure

I have data from several planar uniaxial tests and want to plot stress-strain figures and put the Young's modulus, which is defined as the slope of the stress-strain graph, in a list that will eventually contain all young's moduli.

I wrote the following code, but matlab did not generate any figures or saved any to my computer:

```
% Step 1: Define the directory where your text files are located
directory = 'C:\Users\Biologisch';

% Step 2: Get a list of files in the directory
files = dir(directory);

% Define the column indices you want to extract
columnIndices = [1, 2, 3];  % Modify this as per your requirement

% Define custom names for the result lists
listNames = {'Crosshead', 'Load', 'Time'};  % Modify this with your custom names
all_E = [];

% Step 3: Initialize result lists with custom names to store the results for each column
numColumns = numel(columnIndices);
resultLists = cell(1, numColumns);
for i = 1:numColumns
     resultLists{i} = [];
end

W0 = 45;               %Breedte begin [mm]
D = 4*10^-3;           %Dikte [mm]
W = 40;                %Breedte eind
Area = (D)*(W0)*10^(-6);

% Number of lines to skip (in this case, 8 lines)
linesToSkip = 8;

% Initialize divisionResultsList as an empty cell array
divisionResultsList = cell(1, length(files));

% Step 4: Iterate over the list of files
set(0, 'DefaultFigureVisible', 'on');
for i = 1:length(files)
    filename = files(i).name;
    
    % Step 5: Check if the file is a text file
    if endsWith(filename, '.txt')
        
        % Open the text file
        fileID = fopen(fullfile(directory, filename));
        
        % Skip the first 8 lines
        for j = 1:linesToSkip
            fgetl(fileID);
        end
        
        % Read the remaining lines using textscan
        data = textscan(fileID, '%f');
        
        % Close the file
        fclose(fileID);
        
        % Calculation of stress and strain
        crossheadColumn = data{columnIndices(1)};
        loadColumn = data{columnIndices(2)};
        Stress = loadColumn ./ Area;
        L0 = crossheadColumn(1);
        %calculate strain from crosshead data
        Strain_length = (crossheadColumn-L0)/L0;   
        Strain_width = (W0-W)/W;

        % Store the division results in the divisionResultsList
        divisionResultsList{i} = Stress;
        
        p = polyfit(Strain_length,Stress,1);
        f = polyval(p,Strain_length);     % To fit the polynomial on the preferred x coordinates
        E    = p(1)
        all_E = [all_E;E];
        
        %plot stress-strain curve
        figure(1)
        plot(Strain_length,Stress,'b')
        hold on 
        plot(Strain_length,f,'r')
        xlabel('Strain')
        ylabel('Stress [MPa]')
        title(['File: ', files(i).name])
        legend('Stress-strain curve','Linear fit')
        hold off

        %save plot to folder
        saveas(gcf, fullfile(directory, 'Stress-strain curve', [filename '.png']));
    end
end
```

Comment: Use the debugger to step through your program, check that variables such as `file` and `filename` contain the values you expect, and that the conditions you test work correctly. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html

Comment: write `drawnow` or `pause(0.1)` after the `hold off`.

Comment: The debugger does not seem to give any bugs.
I added drawnow and now I get the error:
Index exceeds the number of array elements (1).

Error in inlezen_data (line 56)
        loadColumn = data{columnIndices(2)};

Comment: “The debugger does not seem to give any bugs.” The debugger is not supposed to give bugs. It is supposed to help you debug your program: it helps you see what values variables have while the program is running, see which branches the program takes, etc. You are supposed to use the debugger to verify that the program logic follows your intended logic. Is anything different from what you expect it to be?

Comment: “I added drawnow and now I get the error …” This makes no sense. Adding `drawnow` in one part of the code is not going to cause an error in another part of the code. Something else must have changed too.

Answer (score 1):

**1.-** The MATLAB and Microsoft DOS command`dir` both work alike:

Both take all the files in the folder, to build the requested list.

It may be the case that the files `.` (go 1 level down) and `..` (go 1 level up) are also included in the raw list of files that you use.

I had a similar problem time ago and the solution is to exclude files `.` and `..`

Then you can start processing whatever files containing data.

**2.-** Also, if you share with the readers of your question one file with data, attaching it to the question, or at least a sample of it, then readers will be a assess whether the data in the file is read correctly, or any other point.